# Json pre processing in java

Tags: java, json

I have json with different fieldNames carrying the values of my interest. They come from different sources. I want to get those fields of my interest into one common name. For example:

This is the raw json:

```
{"movieName":"A","Leadactor":"","leadActress":"","movieTitle":"","hero":"","heroine":"","source":"IMDB"}
{"movieName":"","Leadactor":"","leadActress":"","movieTitle":"B","hero":"B1","heroine":"B2","source":"Netflix"}
{"movieName":"C","Leadactor":"C1","leadActress":"C2","movieTitle":"","hero":"","heroine":"","source":"IMDB"}
{"movieName":"D","Leadactor":"D1","leadActress":"D2","movieTitle":"","hero":"","heroine":"","source":"IMDB"}
{"movieName":"","Leadactor":"","leadActress":"","movieTitle":"E","hero":"E1","heroine":"E2","source":"Netflix"}
```

for source imdb the fields of my interest are different from the fields of interest for source netflix. My final goal is to show them in table in front end. So trying to get my fields of interest into common fields.

i want to convert it into:

```
{Name:"A",Actor"A1",Actress"A2","source":"IMDB"}
{Name:"B",Actor"B1",Actress"B2","source":"Netflix"}
{Name:"C",Actor"C1",Actress"C2","source":"IMDB"}
{Name:"D",Actor"D1",Actress"D2","source":"IMDB"}
{Name:"E",Actor"E1",Actress"E2","source":"Netflix"}
```

The solution i am thinking is to use regex to remove all fields with empty values then replace movieName and movieTitle to Name. similarly for other fields.

Is there a much better way to handle this problem.( The json i get is very huge. So looking for super fast way to preprocess it.)

Comment: Use a JSON library instead of regex.

Comment: I used jackson and gson earlier. they are creating java objects which i am assume is overkill to display them in front end. I mean i have to create 10,000 java objects for 1000 json results.I am looking for super fast and memory efficient way to do it as json i get is very huge.

Comment: You can use [json-simple](http://code.google.com/p/json-simple/) which is simple, as the name implies. Look at Decoding example number 4, you can decode a simple object into a map, modify the map and re-encode from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My advise is to use gson and covert above JSON string to a Map like this:

```
Type type = new TypeToken<Map<String, String>>(){}.getType();
Map<String, String> map =
                 gson.fromJson("{'key1':'foo','key2':'bar', 'key3', ''}", type);
```

Once you get your map then simlpy iterate and remove all elements with empty values. After that you can generate your JSON string back from this map.

Comment: Hi @anubhava, I get a stream of json. i read line by line to do th stuff you said. Our json is big. so it takes 10 seconds to process. do you think threading can help here or any other suggestion to speed it up.

Comment: @javaMan: Since this question addressed a different issue (pasring JSON string) rather than this timing issue I suggest you to pls create a new question here on SO with your timing problem so that you can get much better answers.

Comment: i posted new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15794393/json-preprocessing-performance-issue

Answer (score 1):

You can easily do that by creating your own JSON "adder?" `json.org` has a good **JSON** library, your code would look something like this.

```
    public static void addJSON(JSONObject one, JSONObject two){
    while(one.keys().hasNext()){
        String key = (String) one.keys().next();
        try{
            if(one.getString(key).equals("")){
                one.put(key, two.get(key));
            }
        }catch(JSONException e){

        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a JSON Streaming parser like [json-simple](https://code.google.com/p/json-simple/) or [Jackson](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonHome).

They are really fast, memory efficient, saves you tons of encoding headaches and are easy to implement on simple structures like yours.

Answer (score 1):

JSON has context free grammar. And REGEX cannot parse such grammars reliably.

For example this JSON is impossible to parse reliably with regex :

```
{movie : "Apocalypse Now", director : {first_name: "Francis", last_name: "Ford Coppola"}}
```

Because it has nested curly bracket, regex will match next to last bracket as closing in whole expression.
In other words , when there is nested expressions (JSON, XML, javascript etc) use specialized parser, because regex just can not handle it.