# Json preprocessing performance issue

Tags: java, regex, json, jackson, gson

I have a question here on how to pre process java. I implemented some suggestions and i am able to get it to work. Only concern is performance.

[Json pre processing in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15553977/json-pre-processing-in-java)

I experimented two ways:

one way is using gson i dumped it into hash map. then in getters i look into map to read. It took 12 seconds to do it.

I tried one more approach. I created two classes for two json formats. based on source i am using jaskson to map it to respective class.I created on normalized class( class with general names). Now i am using dozer library to map it to normalized class. In the end all my results are set of normalized class objects. It is taking 8 sec now

I am wondering if there is a quicker way to get this work done. I think in both cases the over head is creating 1000's of objects which i dont want. All i need is to display them in front end in a table.

Does manipulating raw json using regex a good option?

Does threading help?

Any other suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: It depends. If what you are doing is not going to be extended too much in the future, then you can process the file by reading in character by character. Regex may be an OK option, but it depends on the structure of the JSON and what you want to extract - and also whether you can assume the order of the keys (which technically can be unordered).

Answer (score 2):

You can probably use Jackson's stream parser for super-fast performance, if it's what you require. Although before doing so I would seriously do some proper benchmarking, because parsing 1000 objects takes way less then 8 seconds with Jackson. See this [benchmark](https://github.com/eishay/jvm-serializers/wiki) serie; if you can clone the repo and adapt your classes to work inside that framework, you'll get an excellent idea of how Jackson behaves with your data class. I suspect that your problem is not with Jackson but with someplace else in your code: a profiler can help a lot in there.